# Systematic way to monitor FourSquare real-time API?

Tags: foursquare

Is there a systematic/programmatic way to monitor for real-time push notification failures? I've found that the real time API notifications can fail intermittently and I would like to be notified when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Usually pushes "fail" because of errors on the application's end, essentially whenever your push URL doesn't return a 200. You will still receive the push from Foursquare though, so assiduous monitoring/logging of all pushes to your app should help you identify when they fail.

If you're doing a lot of processing after receiving a push from us, you may be returning a 200 too slowly. Foursquare will assume the request timed out and report it as a failed push. To mitigate this, you should always return a 200 immediately, then do any processing.

It rarely happens, but sometimes the error could be coming from Foursquare's end. For the latest on platform status, you should follow [@foursquareAPI](https://twitter.com/foursquareapi) on Twitter, where we communicate downtime and other updates.

Comment: I agree this is normally the case. What I noticed (only once so far) was a scenario where FourSquare pushes were failing with a connection exception on the FourSquare side *most* of the time. I used the console to repeatedly push the same checkin from the same user and about 1 in 5 times it would work, the other 4 times it would fail with the connection error. (When this occurred, other connections to the server were working fine from multiple clients.)

I realize this failure mode is an edge case, but I'd still like to know when it happens.

Comment: Ah, was that earlier in the week? Pushes temporarily went wonky a few days ago, but it should now be better. Again, we communicated that through [Twitter](https://twitter.com/foursquareAPI/status/308721696662228993) so follow for the latest!